# SignalR для asp net core 2.0 устанавливается с помощью NETFramework?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, nuget

Создал проект ASP NET Core 2.0 Angular. Пытался подключить SignalR, но при установке пакетов Nuget получил вот это

[image: Обозреватель решений]
[image: Список ошибок]

Почему пакеты установились с помощью NETFramework? Кто дал им такое указание?

Comment: отключать восстановление пакетов не пробовали?

Comment: @Anatol, а смысл? Устанавливается пакет с теми же косяками

Comment: в предупреждении сказано, что пакет был восстановлен, поэтому вполне логично предположить, что надо попробовать установить без восстановления. смысла нет, если знаешь, что это не поможет

Comment: @Anatol, я не знаю, как отключается восстановление. Но руководствуясь логикой, могу предположить, что если после установки я все равно имею первую картинку, то не имеет значения, будут они восстановлены при сборке или нет.

Answer (score 0):

Ты используешь SignalR для .Net Framework а не для .Net Core,потому и ругается. Установи Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR